# String to vector in C, Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I write a simple function to make a `C` string (NOT C++) to a vector for function `execvp` in Linux.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** vecting(char *cstring) {

    int w_count = 0;           //word count
    char *flag = cstring;

    while (*flag != '\0') {
        if (*flag == ' ' || *flag == '\n' || *flag == '\t')
            *flag = '\0';
            flag++;
        else {
            w_count++;
            while (*flag != ' ' && *flag != '\n' && *flag != '\t' && *flag != '\0')
                flag++;
        }
    }

    char **cvector = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*(w_count+1));
    cvector[w_count] = NULL;
    int v_count;                //vector count

    for (v_count = 0, flag = cstring; v_count < w_count; v_count++) {
        while (*flag == '\0')
            flag++;
        cvector[v_count] = flag;
        while (*flag != '\0')
            flag++;
    }
    return cvector;
}

int main()
{
    char *p = "This is a BUG";
    char **argv = vecting(p);
    char **temp;

    for (temp = argv; *temp != NULL; temp++)
        printf("%s\n", *temp);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I it'get `Segmentation fault`.

Then I debug it, I just found, When run

`*flag = '\0';  //(in line 12)`

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

at that time `*flag = ' '`

I couldn't unstand why program received signal SIGSEGV when program change `cstring`

Answer (score 6):

```
char *p = "This is a BUG";
```

is a string literal and it's **undefined behavior** to modify it. `char *flag = cstring;` means `flag` points to the same location (which happens to be read-only memory) as `p`. What you're attempting to do (as it is now) is illegal.

Try with

```
char p[] = "This is a BUG";
```

Comment: In the past, it is possible to modified, because the literal string is not marked read-only in memory. Compilers nowadays mark the memory storing the literal string read-only, so you will get SEGFAULT regardless if you try to modify it.

Comment: @nhahtdh really? Do you have a reference for that? The standard says it's undefined behavior, and I tend to trust it more.

Comment: @nhahtdh also, undefined behavior means anything can happen. It's not required to crash. And what do you mean in the past? You mean a decade ago? Because both C++03 and C++11 say this is UB. Don't know about previous versions, but that should be enough.

Comment: It is not required to crash, but it is usually implemented to be read-only, and crash upon modification: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/STR30-C.+Do+not+attempt+to+modify+string+literals . I heard from my professor that you can modify literal string in the past since it is not marked read-only. Can you make small modification to your post so that I can remove the down vote?

Comment: @nhahtdh for future, please reserve downvotes for when an answer is obviously flawed. I have nothing against them if they come with solid arguments. :)

Comment: The reason I down voted is because I though that the valid example doesn't work. It is my fault for not go through thorough testing to check. Since I am learning something from your answer, +1.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of getting SIGSEGV is that `"This is the bug"` string was placed into const section. When program is loaded corresponding memory area is marked read-only. When program tries to write to read-only memory area it receives segmentation fault.